# Matrix Exponent - equivalent of a rotation matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation, exponential-function

Every [Rotation Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)can be represented as a power of e with exponent a skew symmetric matrix.

In particular, if we have a rotation matrix ${R}\in\mathbb R^{3 \times 3,}$ then there will be a skew symmetric $B$ such that $R=\mathrm{e}^B.\tag 1$ How do we prove that and also for a given $R$ how do we calculate $B$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rotation matrix $R$ is orthogonally diagonalizable with eigenvalues of absolute value one, i.e.,
$$
R=U^* D U,
$$ 
where $D=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$, with $\lvert d_j\rvert=1$, for all $j=1,\ldots,n$,
and $U^*U=I$. Clearly, as $\lvert d_j\rvert=1$, there exists a $\vartheta_j\in\mathbb R$, such that
$$
d_j=\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta_j}, \quad j=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Now it is clear that if $B=U^*\varTheta U$, where $\varTheta=\mathrm{diag}(i\vartheta_1,\ldots,i\vartheta_n)$, then
$$
R=\mathrm{e}^B.
$$
We have used here the fact that, if $A=V^*DV$, then $\mathrm{e}^A=V^*\mathrm{e}^DV$.

Comment: Well explained. I just want to emphasize that for 3d case, there is no need to go through eigen computaion. You can just apply Rodrigues formula and get the log function easily. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_angle#Log_map_from_SO.283.29_to_so.283.29)

Comment: @TroyWoo Good reference. DCA matrix to axis angle in two simple steps. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

What we have given is a rotation matrix R. We know there exits a form $e^B$ for every R. Now as per the [paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0377042709007791/1-s2.0-S0377042709007791-main.pdf?_tid=d357c010-23eb-11e4-bb9b-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1408045829_061fabba3e57c9bb585b8448eda047bc) $B=log R \tag 1$

$ \theta = \arccos\left( \frac{\mathrm{trace}(R) - 1}{2} \right) \tag 2$ 
 $ \log R =  \{ \begin{matrix}
0 & \mathrm{if} \; \theta = 0 \\
\frac{\theta}{2 \sin(\theta)} (R - R^\top) & \mathrm{if} \; \theta \ne 0 \; \mathrm{and} \; \theta \in (-\pi, \pi)  \end{matrix} \tag 3$